# Can I change the default Access 2010 view to allow for "Window"ed objects?

Tags: microsoft-access-2010

Before Access 2007, Microsoft Access was an MDI Container.  For those who aren't developers, this means that each time you opened a DB object (i.e. Data Table, Query, Form) it appeared as a window within your application.  You could Minimize, Maximize, Restore the windows as you needed, and they were all contained within the MS Access Application.

I started using Access 2010, for the first time about 6 months.  I know that Access 2003 is long gone, but the change to a tab interface is something that is starting to drive me insane.

I have a HUGE monitor that I use to layout, analyze and reference a lot of data from different objects.  Having to switch tabs, constantly, is highly-unproductive for me.

Is there any way, possibly by some deeply buried setting, that I can turn Access 2010 into an MDI container, much like older versions of Access?

Comment: No, there is no feature like that.  I've tried all of the obvious steps.  In fact, I'm quite doubtful there is a solution to this problem, but I can't find where anyone has asked this before.  Certainly there are other data-nerds out there that need to have their eyes jump back-and-forth between 3-5 sets of data in Access!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it for 2007/10/13:

- *File* tab (or the Orb if using 2007)
- *Options*
- *Current Database*
- Under "*Document Window Options*" choose "**Overlapping Windows**" instead of "**Tabbed Documents**".

[image: Access 2013 options window]

Close and re-open the DB and you'll have MDI-style Windows.

[image: Access 2013 in MDI-style mode]

Comment: Excellent! You have just made my week!